# SVN - Project for which branching have an impact for next branch to be done

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging

**Context**

I have setup a simple process when using in my company for a project, which is, every time a new feature is in development and not yet tested, it should remain in its branch, only when validation is passed, the branch can be merged back to the trunk. This part is working great, but since now a second developer is also working on the project, and due to a specific data format in the project.

In the project folder, we have a "dictionary" file which contains key=value pairs, but the key is simply a digit (this is legacy and cannot be changed). Then the keys in this "dictionary" file are being used in many other sources files/data files. Usually the key values are used and added sequentially.

**Example**

Let's say in the trunk r100, the latest entry in the dictionary is 1000.

Dev A create branch A from trunk r100, and then in this branch adds 200 entries in the dictionary, the dictionary latest entry is now 1200. Dev A use the entries 1001 to 1200 to develop new source or data files.

Then Dev B create branch A from trunk r100 (since branch A is not validated it is not yet re-integrated), and thus at this time, in branch B, the dictionary latest entry is 1000. Dev B adds 300 entries in the dictionary in this branch, the dictionary latest entry is now 1300. Dev B use the entries 1001 to 1300 to develop new source or data files.

Dev A finish branch A validation, and merge back/reintegrate its branch A to the trunk, no problem, the dictionary in the trunk is now the same than the branch A one and thus contains 1200 entries.

The problem is now that if Dev B wants to update the branch B from the trunk (or merge the branch B directly back the trunk), there will be a LOT of conflict in the dictionary file, since there will be 200 entries with common keys (1001 to 1200) but different values. Resolving the conflict at this time is annoying and a little bit of a pain for the dev team.

**Possible solutions ?**

I had thought of the following:

1. Every time the dictionary has been committed in one branch, the Dev
   responsible of this branch should merge back the dictionary into the
   trunk. Then when other Dev on other branches update their own branch
   from the trunk, they will get the dictionary content being modified
   on another branch only
2. Devs communicate together when creating a branch a allocate themselves a range of key from the dictionary file,

Solution 1 issue is that in my understanding, it breaks a little the concept of the isolation of the branch itself.

Solution 2 issue is that it's not reliable and not efficient.

I am missing something, is the way to use branch in this case irrelevant ? Maybe the dictionary file should not be branched in the branch and only kept in the trunk (partial branch?!) ?

Thank you in advance for your help and ideas about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two possible ways

1. Logical extending of you solution 1: dictionary not permanently merged into all branches, but exist and used as single common shared resource. SVN:externals, file-level type (require Subversion 1.6+, I'll suggest 1.8.*). Implementation - real dictionary-file exist out of tree of /trunk, dictionary inside trunk is external with **absolute path** to file (not relative, in order to have unchanged target on branching). This way all branches at any time will use one common dictionary (in case of two parallel edits second committer will have to update file before real commit and merge changes with resolving conflicts in keys)
2. Each developer uses not sequential, but a sparse numbering (agreement-based numbering). I.e, in the assumption that no more than 10 developers exist at every moment: Dev 0 uses only 0, 10, 20... Dev 1 - 1, 11, 21... Dev 9 - 9, 19, 29... and dictionary's changes will not intersect in keys on merging

Comment: I like the first suggestion. Nice and neat. I think the external should be added in `trunk` and merged up to existing branches, and any new branches off `trunk` will get it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will try the first you mention next week and let you know how it went. (I will wait a little while longer before accepting an answer)